# Custom Combobox Dropdown trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am working in html for a custom drop down menu. I want to click the arrow and the list to open the hidden options, but nothing happens when i click the arrow? I do not know what is wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter4854/rrmJR/1/

Comment: I inserted a `console.log("foo");` directly before `e.stopPropagation();` and it works. Even after removing the log command. o.O chrome18, win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution might be to just bind the click event on the arrow so that it triggers the click even of the drop down like this:

```
$('.arrow').click(function() {
    $('.custom-select').trigger('click')
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rrmJR/4/)**.

BTW, any reason why you're using such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: Well, if i used a newer one, how would it affect the outcome?

Comment: I'm not saying it necessarily would, but there are improvements and bug fixes in newer versions.

Comment: You can just download the latest version from jquery.com or link to  hosted version from jquery.com or Google.

Answer (score 0):

I simply put your `.arrow` div into the `custom-select` div and it's working. It doesn't really matter where to put your arrow since you position it absolutely) The working example: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/rrmJR/6/